# Big Problems with Vue CLI and SASS Loader

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli

I'm usally working with React and its acutally very easy to install SASS to react.
I tried with Vue but It wont work.
After I install vue 3 with cli and try to install node and sass I get this error:
SASS Loader cant be resolved.
Is there an tutorial where it tells me step by step how I can work with SASS.

Comment: This is not a proper problem statement. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . There's generally no such problem with SASS that you describe. It's supposed to be workable outside the box when a project is created with Vue CLI. Hint: prefer `sass` (Dart SASS) instead of `node-sass` (legacy) when asked, it causes less problems.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but try installing sass with it

```
npm install sass-loader node-sass --save-dev scss
```